# Connecting Python to Mysql and LibreOffice Calc

Tags: python, mysql, libreoffice-calc

Sorry for the broad title, didnt know how to be specific. So I have created an interface using Tkinter in python. A date is selected using a calender. When I hit submit daily report of LibreOffice Calc type must be opened. I have done the calender part of it. Dont know how to do the opening of report part. Can someone please help? Thank you

Comment: please have a look on how to ask on stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want to interface with LibreOffice using the UNO API?  There is a tutorial at http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html.  Also, LibreOffice Base can connect to MySQL.  Beyond that, it sounds like you're not sure what you're trying to do yet.  That's understandable, but you'll need to work on the project some more until there is a specific question to ask.  Be sure to mention what you've researched online as well.